# I cant import sklearn

Tags: python

I try to import scikit-learn, but there is an error. i installed sklearn, scipy on anaconda. i am using W10 and python 3.5.

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

Comment: What happens when you try `import scipy`?

Comment: it cant find.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'`

Comment: Call `import sys` then call `print(sys.version)`. What does it print out?

Comment: it says `3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]`

Comment: So you are seemingly using the version of python installed by anaconda. How are you launching this version of python?

Comment: [like that]https://s32.postimg.org/h4n060jvp/pythhh.png

i am sorry, i am noob. i am searching "python" on w10

Comment: Try opening `spyder` or typing `spyder` into the command prompt and see if they work.

Comment: yes, it works on spyder. cant i work it on IDLE ?

Comment: what happens when you type "conda install scikit-learn"

Answer (score 2):

In linux there is `pip install <module>` to install a module, and if you are using anaconda then `conda install <module>`, I believe there would be something similar in windows.

If you are sure that you have installed `scipy` module, then probably the python path is not looking for those directories.

You can try a [environment variable `PYTHONPATH` that has a list of directories to append before launching python prompt.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath) OR you can test it for a session by [adding it to `sys.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257747/adding-a-file-path-to-sys-path-in-python)

Comment: thank you, but this is a old question. i used spyder later then, now i can import with manually from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs). it is not a problem for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Use pip to install the packages

1. pip install numpy
2. pip install scipy
3. pip install -U scikit-learn

Ensure you have appropriate privileges for installing globally or in virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), or interpreter setting in [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html):

1. pip install NumPy+mkl
   [numpy-mkl 1.10.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-mkl)
   Install module NumPy+mkl
2. pip install SciPy
   Install module SciPy

Now you can install sklearn.

3. pip install scikit-learn
   Install module scikit-learn

Hope that it is useful.