# How to properly create a package in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Say I have a folder named `foo`. Inside that folder is `__init__.py`, a folder called `test`, and another Python file called `t1.py`. Inside folder `test` is a Python file called `bar.py`, and in that file I am trying to do something like:

```
from foo import t1
```

And it gives me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gmuwork'
```

Do I need to add something to environment variables or `sys.path`?

Comment: Section 6.4 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) should be useful

Comment: @BradSolomon: you're right, and I would say section 6.4.2 specifically, Intra-package References and relative import.

Answer (score 1):

### Absolute import

If you want to use

```
from foo import t1
```

Then yes, `foo` must be contained in `sys.path`.
From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on
>   sys.path looking for the package subdirectory.

In that case take a look at questions such as [adding a file path to sys.path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257747/adding-a-file-path-to-sys-path-in-python).

### Relative import

Alternatively inside of `bar.py` you should be able to use

```
from ..foo import t1
```

as an [intra-package reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).

Lastly: either way, you should put another empty `__init__.py` file inside of `test` to let Python know that folder is a subpackage.