# I am getting a warning while downloading a module using pip

Tags: python

WARNING: The script pipwin.exe is installed in 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanently adding a file path to sys.path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257747/permanently-adding-a-file-path-to-sys-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Add to python paths:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Scripts
```

Type this into cmd!

---

Edit:

If you want this to work permanently, make a .bat file, add that line in, and put in under the Windows>Start menu>Programs>Startup

Comment: thank you for helping, but how would i check if this is working or not

Comment: @HimanshuSharma, I have edited it in case you want a permanent solution.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma Open Command Prompt, and type in that code. Press Windows key and type in 'cmd' and Enter to enter the Command Prompt.