# How Can I add any directory to PATH using Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project which adds a certain directory to the Windows Path Environment variable. But I can't figure out how to add a directory to Path using Python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257747/permanently-adding-a-file-path-to-sys-path-in-python This is a duplicate

Comment: [How to set environment variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python)

Comment: I cant use them in Shell if I use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257747/permanently-adding-a-file-path-to-sys-path-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make sure to run this as an account with Admin privileges

```
import win32com.shell.shell as shell

def addPathToEnv(pathToAdd):
    """
    Add the supplied path the Windows Path Environment variable
    :param pathToAdd: <str> Full path to be added as Path Environment.
    """
    
    commands = f'setx /M PATH "%PATH%;{pathToAdd}"'
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile='cmd.exe', lpParameters='/c '+commands)
```