# Add a DLL permanently to python

Tags: python, dll, operating-system

I have a python file, and it is calling a .pyd file. However, this .pyd file depends on a DLL.

I can get it to work if I either:

- Copy the dll in question to the same location as the .pyd file.
- run the command `os.add_dll_directory('MYPATH\\LOCATION')`

I was wondering if there is a way to add this permanently. I have read and tried what was suggested here: [Permanently adding a file path to sys.path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257747/permanently-adding-a-file-path-to-sys-path-in-python) but unfortunately, creating the .pth file didnt work.

Comment: Define "permanently"...

Comment: Permanently: Every time I start python (e.g., a jupyter notebook) it is available.

Comment: When copying a file in some location, the file stays there either until it's erased or the storage medium goes bad, so that would qualify as "permanently". Note: *.pth* has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found (which I don't like) is to create somewhere in Python path a file `sitecustomize.py` and fill it with the following content:

```py
import os
os.add_dll_directory('C:\\path\\to\your\\dll\folder')
os.add_dll_directory('C:\\path\\to\another\\dll\folder')
```

However, I am much missing any equivalent of the Linux `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.