# How do you permanently save a 3rd party module in Python 2.7.9?

Tags: python, module

I am new to programming and have been following some tutorials for learning the basics of Python 2.7.9 syntax. I am also using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

The tutorial is discussing how to create, save, import, and test custom modules for Python in Windows OS. I have been successful at doing so in Ubuntu, but only after adding a temporary directory path in shell for `PYTHONPATH` to search.

The default `sys.path` directories are:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`
```

As you can see, the default paths all fall under the `/usr` directory.

2 solutions come to mind to fix this problem:

1. How can I save under the `/usr` path directory?
2. How can I permanently add a new path directory?

However, attempting to save the file `testmod.py` under `/usr` prompts the I/O Error message:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'usr/local/lib/Python-2.7.9/testmod.py'
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3722248/3001761, or considered writing a `setup.py` and installing your module?

Answer (score 0):

You need `sudo` to save in /usr but another way is to simply add the path to your modules to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/my_mods"
```

where `my_mods` is in your home directory, `.profile` *gets executed automatically by the DisplayManager during the start-up process desktop session as well as by the login shell when one logs in from the textual console*

`.bashrc` will work when you use the bash shell to start a program.

You will need to logout and login after setting `.profile` or use `source .bashrc` if you go with the bashrc option for the settings to take effect.

[environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

To check your PYTHONPATH use `echo $PYTHONPATH`:

```
~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/padraic/mymods/
```